# Image won't correctly adjust to the height of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to set the height of an image to the height of an adjacent div.

The issue is that the last `<p>` element is appearing under the image, even after using JavaScript to grab the height of the div and use it to set the height of the image.

```js
$("#here").find('img').css("height", $(".text").outerHeight());
```

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="here">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2Mjg1OTk0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MTA3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="RED">
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Movie: RED</h2>
    <p>When his peaceful life is threatened by a high-tech assassin, former black-ops agent Frank Moses reassembles his old team in a last ditch effort to survive and uncover his assailants.</p>
    <p>Movie Categories Action, Comedy, Crime</p>
    <p>111 min long</p>
    <p>Some actors were Bruce Willis, Mary-Louise Parker, Heidi von Palleske, Karl Urban</p>
    <p>Rated: PG-13</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</div>
```

You can reproduce the issue at http://thecodesee.pe.hu/ by clicking the submit button.

---

Here is my desired outcome:

[image]

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: looks like both images do not have same height

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal The first picture I posted, I manually edited the image's height to show how I want the outcome to be.

Comment: @TheCodesee  you have to put image into a div then its works fine as shown in my snippent

Comment: @AmanKumar doesn't solve the issue. you can reproduce the issue at http://thecodesee.pe.hu/ by clicking the submit button.

Comment: Change outerHeight to innerHeight as my script and check

Comment: @AmanKumar Tried it, still doesn't resolve the issue. Have you reproduced it on  thecodesee.pe.hu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "search.php",
         success: function(data) {
            $("#here").css("display", "block");
            $("#here").html(data).promise().done(function() {
               $("#here").find('img').css("height", $(".text").outerHeight());
               var $img = $("#here").find('img');

                $img.on('load', function() {
                    $("#here").find('img').css("height", $(".text").outerHeight());
                });
            });

     }
  });
```

Comment: I have to thank you SO MUCH for this answer! This issue has been bugging me for almost a week now and I don't know what I would of done without your brilliant answer! :) :) Thank you so much again! +1

Comment: You are most welcome @TheCodesee . Its just because of your .text class height is different before image loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The image is sized only when the page loads or only when the function is called. I believe you have to write a window.onresize() event to constantly change the image size according to the layout.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            window.onresize = function(){
            $("#here").find('img').css("height", $(".text").outerHeight());     
            }

        });
```

However this doesnt cater for the first time load. The div seems to be rendered after the size is being retrieved. You might want to ensure the div has been rendered before you grab the outerHeight(), by using .ready() for that patricular

Comment: Thank you also for this answer; and using your initiative for something which I hadn't even asked in my original question. This is a very useful code. + 1

Answer (score 0):

you  can fix it with css simple css code ; by adjusting width dimensions like :

```
 img {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.text {

  width : 75%;
}
```